# Ruby on Rails - dependency injection conundrum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, dependency-injection, ruby-on-rails-2

I'm working on a Rails 2 app and the lack of a dependency injection container has me wondering about dependencies and their impact on unit testing. I have the following:

Controller

```
def some_action
  object_a = ClassA.new
  object_a.do_something
end
```

ClassA

```
def do_something
  # some code, then...
  object_b = ClassB.new(params)
end
```

Because ClassA's do_something method instantiates object_b, I won't be able to mock object_b's behavior in a unit test. The way around that is to pass that initialization param from the controller to ClassA, then in ClassA's initialize, I could pass in the needed params for ClassB.

By doing that, however, I expose the controller to a knowledge about ClassB (it's init params) that it shouldn't need to know about.

Thoughts?

Comment: you don't need all that DI stuff in ruby. you have meta-programming and all the test-frameworks implement whatever mocking and stubbing that is needed.

Comment: also rails-2? wow, that must be an old piece of code...

Comment: What about isolating dependencies as much as possible? That's what DI containers help with the most.

Comment: usually the answer is, you don't need that in ruby. while it's a good best practice to design your software to inject dependencies, it's strictly not necessary in ruby because of meta programming. there are a bunch of different paradigms in a dynamic open language like ruby. learn them first before thinking about a di container. i recommend reading Design Patterns in Ruby.